# Получить ссылку на родительский класс

Tags: c++, ооп

Как воспользоваться конструктором копирования родительского класса в конструкторе копирования дочернего?

```
class A {
  int a;
public:
  A(const A & other) {
    a = other.a;
  }
};

class B : public A {
  int b;
public:
  B(const B & other) : A(/*what*/) {
    b = other.b;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В вашем примере просто напрямую

```
B(const B & other) : A(other) {
  b = other.b;
}
```

Если бы в вашем классе `A` были еще какие-то конструкторы, которые приводили бы к неоднозначности такого вызова или к вызову неправильного конструктора, то пришлось бы выполнить явное приведение типа

```
B(const B & other) : A(static_cast<const A &>(other)) {
  b = other.b;
}
```

но в вашем случае в этом нет необходимости.

Comment: Спасибо за дополнение: в реальном коде нужно было выполнить приведение. Здесь не указывал дополнительных конструкторов, чтобы не перегружать лишней информацией.